# Regex for strings with no three identical consecutive characters

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

I wanna ask what the regular expression for the strings having the property in the title should be. For binary string with no three consecutive 0, it's quite a simple regex (1|01|001)*|(0|00|$\epsilon$) but I found its very difficult for a normal alphabet string. Do you have any suggestion/solution for that?

**Note:** Those strings don't contain **any** three identical consecutive characters. For example, they do not have $aaa$, $bbb$, $ccc$, etc. in their content.

Thanks,

Comment: you can have the string 111 with your regular expression.

Comment: @Xoff sorry, its no three consecutive 0. Just edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't easy to product a complement of regular expression. Very long and exhausting calculations :(

For alphabet $\{a,b\}$ (and if I didn't miscalculate) it is something like

> ((a|ba|bba)(aba|abba|ba|bba)*(abb|ab|bb|a|b|$\varepsilon$))|bb|b|$\varepsilon$

which is ... bulky.

You need to convert your regex to DFA, then turn all non-terminal state into terminal states and vice versa, then convert the resulting DFA to regex back.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676431/regular-expressions-with-repeated-characters) there is a well-done example of it.

Comment: Thank you, it's a huge expression indeed. The example is very helpful and easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

This is very difficult to have a small regexp using only sum operator `|` and star `*`, but in javascript you can do something like :

```
((.)\2?(?!\2))*
```

1. `(.)` is the second group and match any letter
2. `\2?` is an optional repetition of the previous letter
3. `(?!\2)` is a condition : the same letter does not follow this expression

It's much easier because you can capture group and force them not to be followed by some expression.

Comment: So I think it could not apply to science regex...

Answer (score -1):

\b([a-zA-Z0-9])\1\1+\b
checks any character that appears more than 3 times

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This answer doesn't seem intelligible. Please consider [editing](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and/or elaborating.